# Extending an access expression to check for value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm currently trying to wrestle with expression trees to make a bit of magic happen, but I keep hitting error after error.

I've got some properties like this on some of my domain objects (Entity Framework)

```
Expression<Func<DomainObject, LinkedDomainObject>> IncludeExpr
{
   get {
      return o => o.SomeLinkedObject;
   }
}
```

and another expression that checks that linked object for equality on some property (e.g. ID).

I did have an expression that also checked that linked object for being null, and that way I could compose a `NotNull` and `Matched ID` expression by inverting the null check expression and combining it via `AndAlso` with the ID check expression.

I want to take the `o => o.SomeLinkedObject` expression and `linkedObject => linkedObject.ID == idVar` expressions and mash them together to effectively get:

`o => o.LinkedObject != null && o.LinkedObject.Id == idVar`

But I can't for the life of me work out how I'd get an expression tree together based on those two separate expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take a moment to create a helper method that can make solving this problem very straightforward.  If we create a method that lets us compose expressions as easily as we can compose delegates, this becomes very easy.  Our `Compose` method will accept an expression, and another that takes the output of the first and transforms it into something else, creating a new expression that can transform something of the type of the input of the first into the output of the second:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This is dependent on the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}

internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Now we can create an `IsNotNull` transformation very easily:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> IsNotNull<TSource, TKey>(
    this Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> expression)
{
    return expression.Compose(key => key != null);
}
```

As for `And`-ing two expressions together, the easiest option if using a LINQ query provider is to just call `Where` on each expression separately, if that's an option.  If not, you can use a `PrediacteBuilder` to `And` or `Or` two expressions together:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks solid to me, i might have added, take a look at LinqKit in general. it has Predicate builder and some more..

Comment: @philsoady I'm well aware of LinqKit.  I prefer my solution for `PredicateBuilder`.  It does the same thing in far less work/code.

Comment: @Servy Thank you! This worked for me, I didn't need to get the `PredicateBuilder` in there in the end, I finally ended up being able to do: `var nExpr = GroupIncludeExpression.IsNotNull().AndAlso(GetGroupMatchesIdExpresssion(_groupId));` by using the `Compose` method and the replacement visitor.

Comment: @Servy, you may be aware of it, but not everyone is.  Your solution is fine and i had already +1 the solution. Chill...